# Java XMPP clint with smack 4.1 NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle, build.gradle, smack

I am trying to write XMPP Clint using smack 4.1.1. I have added smack jar files into build path. I am using eclipse IDE to write the code.

However, when I am trying to run application I get NoClassDefFoundErrors. I fixed some of these errors adding xpp3, jxmpp and minidns jar files into the build path. Yet, I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jxmpp/util/cache/ExpirationCache
at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.dns.minidns.MiniDnsResolver.<clinit>(MiniDnsResolver.java:46)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.loadSmackClass(SmackInitialization.java:213)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.parseClassesToLoad(SmackInitialization.java:193)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:163)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.processConfigFile(SmackInitialization.java:148)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackInitialization.<clinit>(SmackInitialization.java:116)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.getVersion(SmackConfiguration.java:96)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<clinit>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:38)
at JabberSmackAPI.login(JabberSmackAPI.java:29)
at JabberSmackAPI.main(JabberSmackAPI.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jxmpp.util.cache.ExpirationCache
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 12 more
```

How to fix this issue?

In the internet, it is advised to use gradle or maven for building the same. If so, can you help me how to use the same? I have never used them before.

Comment: are you able to resolve your issue yet???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per below stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jxmpp.util.cache.ExpirationCache
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

It seem You are missing jxmpp-util-cache-0.5.0-alpha2.jar in your class path.  [Download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxmpp/jxmpp-util-cache/0.5.0-alpha2) and add this jar to your `lib/` directory of your application .

> In the internet, it is advised to use gradle or maven for building the
>   same. If so, can you help me how to use the same?

Create a meven project in eclipse .If you are new to meven project refer

> [How to create a Java project with Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/)

And add Below dependencies to  pom.xml of your meven build project

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
      <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-im</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For more details refer this [link](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide#with-maven)